# Is there a chrome extension where I can enter a keyboard command to automatically open a web page or find the web page if already opened?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts

I have a web page I am using as a call center. It is usually open in its own chrome window or tab. I have a shortcut command to auto hang up but it only works if you are focused on that page. So now I am wondering if there is a chrome extension where you could do a quick keyboard command that would allow me to go through my tabs/chrome windows and find the page with my call center and make that the focused page so I could enter my keyboard command to auto hangup. I have gone through a good amount of extensions with some being close to what I need like AutoControl but the issue there is I was only able to open up new windows with the web page instead of being able to just go to the already opened one. Any advice here would be really appreciated!

Comment: Chrome's latest version on desktop comes with tab search inbuild in the search bar. on Mobile you can use this: https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/10490587?hl=en   feature.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a programming site, here is a solution using pure code.

Use the following [AutoControl script](https://www.autocontrol.app/scripting):

```js
let THE_URL = 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67491725' ;
let THE_TAB_ID ; //this will contain the ID of the existing tab or the new tab

//Find the ID of the tab with the desired URL
for( let [tabId, {url}] of await ACtl.getTabInfo('#allTabs') ){
    if( url.startsWith(THE_URL) )
        THE_TAB_ID = tabId ;
}
//If there's no tab with that URL, create a new tab
if( !THE_TAB_ID )
    [ THE_TAB_ID ] = await ACtl.openURL(THE_URL, {rightOf: '#currentTab'}) ;

//Activate the tab and focus its window
ACtl.setTabState(THE_TAB_ID, 'active focused') ;
```

The comments make clear what's happening. You have to iterate through all your tabs and find the one with the desired URL. If you find one, you save the tab ID to a variable.

If that variable is falsy after the iteration, it means there was no tab with that URL, so you have to open a new one.

The script must be run as a [background script](https://www.autocontrol.app/scripting/background-scripts), otherwise you would have to specify a tab in which to run it.

This is how it should look like in the configuration page:
[image: AutoControl's "RUN SCRIPT" action]

The example uses <kbd>F11</kbd> as the trigger, but you can choose any keyboard or mouse shortcut/gesture.
Go to [AutoControl triggers](https://www.autocontrol.app/triggers) for an extensive list of all the possible triggers you can use.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a bit overkill but the feature exists on [Vimium](https://vimium.github.io/)

After you install the extension, you hit "Ctrl-t", and it will bring up a dialog to search through your opened tabs.